# TSQL Openquery not creating temp table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, openquery

I have the following code:

```
declare @cQuery      varchar(2000);
declare @cTSQL       varchar(2000);
declare @cLinkServer varchar(20);
declare @cTable      varchar(20);

set @cQuery = 'SELECT iln.product_nbr FROM axs.pub.ivc_line iln';
set @cLinkServer = 'RBDAX1';
set @cTable = '#tempInv';

if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tempInv') is not null
    drop table #tempInv

--SELECT * INTO #tempInv FROM OPENQUERY(RBDAX1,'SELECT iln.product_nbr FROM axs.pub.ivc_line iln');

set @cTSQL = 
    'SELECT * '
    + ' INTO #tempInv '
    + ' FROM OPENQUERY(RBDAX1,''SELECT iln.product_nbr FROM axs.pub.ivc_line iln'')'
    ;

exec ( @cTSQL );
```

When I call exec ( @cTSQL ); the temp table has not been created.

When I run the commented out line:

```
SELECT * 
INTO #tempInv 
FROM OPENQUERY(RBDAX1, 'SELECT iln.product_nbr FROM axs.pub.ivc_line iln');
```

the temp table is created just fine.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Just a note: The ultimate goal here is to pass variables to openquery because my real query is 90 lines of code. Based on my research the only way to do this is to set the query in a variable and openquery does not allow variables as parameters unless I use TSQL to EXEC the openquery statement.

Comment: It was created, just not where you think it should be. The temp table would be scope to your dynamic sql. Once you come back that temp table is dropped because the connection that created it is closed. Why do you need dynamic sql here?

Comment: The query that I need to run against the linkserver is over 90 lines long, so I would like to assign it to a variable, then pass that variable to openquery. If I hard code the query into open query, it's a mess.

Comment: Huh? How does making it dynamic sql cause it to be less of a mess? It is adding a whole extra layer of complexity, syntax and logistical challenges where you don't need that. If you really feel you need dynamic sql you could create the table first, then have your dynamic sql insert into the temp table. It would still be in scope there because it was created outside the dynamic sql. But for me, that is creating extra work.

Comment: @sean lange Thanks for the advice. So I already have the query written but it has to be passed as a string to the database it's querying. So when putting the query into openquery, the was I have it formatted, concatenating the string on several lines, it created a nightmare with the "tick" marks :) I think I'm gonna to the static table route and just insert the data into it and be done. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot create a temp table this way. The temp table is created but then 'goes away' the minute the query ends. You can create a table and do an insert/select.